# Error message in my R-markdown file (post-knit)

Tags: r, leaflet, r-markdown, gis, r-sf

I'm using a markdown file to build a leaflet map in R, and after I've knitted my document, I get this error message in my rmd file:

`## although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_union assumes that they are planar`

Could you help me? I believe what I'm trying to display that keep erroring out like this are some of my tables.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [here](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf6.html#although-coordinates-are-longitudelatitude-xxx-assumes-that-they-are-planar):

> Most (but not all) of the geometry calculating routines used by sf come from the GEOS library. This library considers coordinates in a two-dimensional, flat, Euclidian space. For longitude latitude data, this is not the case.

It seems it has to do with the arguments you are passing to `st_union()`